# Different Voltage Battery Backup Circuit

Tags: battery-charging

I saw a circuit on a website to make a backup battery circuit for a rechargeable 12v battery circuit.
[image: Circuit 1]

However, I don't anticipate regular power outages, so I believe that one non-rechargeable 9v battery will last for more than the life of this project.
I came up with the following circuit modeled after the first circuit ([And a voltage regulator circuit I saw](http://www.techulator.com/attachments/Resources/10562-75631-V-Voltage-Regulator.jpg)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN5ob0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Is it dangerous to mix different voltages like this? I heard it could be for transformers, but what about a battery? Would the circuit only use the battery if the transformer is disconnected, and finally, does it look like it would work?

Thanks!

Comment: Very nice circuit! I came across the first one too, but I find it problematic because it doesn't account for the diode voltage drops. Yours seems to handle this issue well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your circuit looks fine to me !

The diodes are a bit over specified though, the 1N5406 can handle 3 A, in your
case 1 A should suffice (the LM7805 is not going to pull more than 1 A).
So you could use 1N4001 instead. But if you have the 1N5406 lying around, you can
use those, it will work just as well.

Just build it and enjoy :-)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I had already ordered the 3A diodes before I made the circuit, since I mistakenly thought that I needed 3A because the transformer is 12V 3A. If I ever build more of the circuit though, I will go with the 1A diodes as recommended!