# Switching between battery 12 VDC and 24 VDC power

Tags: power, switching, brownout

I need to have a device held up by a 12 V battery supply during brown outs but then restored back to normal running 24 VDC without any power interruption.
The unit draws about 350 mA at 24 V.
I cannot have any loss of power as the program becomes corrupted.
Would a relay and capacitor work in this situation? It needs to be reliable and basic if possible.

Comment: Use a relais. Simple, easy. Search for it.

Comment: Does [THIS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178795/different-voltage-battery-backup-circuit) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC7qol.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The highest voltage wins. Expect a 0.7 V drop in voltage across the conducting diode.*

Comment: Hi Transistor, Use of Schottky diodes could reduce the voltage drop to around 0.4 V.